# JavaScript Regex needs to catch new lines

Tags: javascript, regex

So, I have:

```
/`{3}(?:(.*$)\n)?([\s\S]*)`{3}/m
```

Which matches things like this fine:

````
```javascript
alert('Hello World');
//It wont break even if i throw in ``` in this comment!
```
````

But unfortunately it also matches:

````
```javascript
alert('Hello World');
```

```javascript
alert('OH NOES!');
```
````

As **one** match, but it should be **two**. It should look for everything, including other ``` inside, but once it sees a double line break, it should start looking for another match.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the non-greedy `.*?` instead of `.*`.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like it. Ill mark it right in about 10 mins as it wont let me mark it correct for that long. Sweet thanks!